# Cannot scan the right values of Order date in sql

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch all datas that corresponds in the chosen date range.
So the problem is that. When theres included time in the data. It can't fetch the required data to be displayed. But when I remove the time on it. It displays really well. What can I do to make it right?

EXAMPLE VALUES:

> 1. 2018-10-29 01:21:29pm
> 2. 2018-10-30 01:21:29pm

EXAMPLE VALUES THAT WORKS:

> 1. 2018-10-29
> 2. 2018-10-30

My query:

```
 `"SELECT *,SUBSTRING(order_date,1,10) from orders where order_date >='$fromdate' AND order_date <='$todate'"`
```

Comment: What is the type of `order_date` in your db?

Comment: @B001ᛦ its varchar(500). Because the date comes from php code.

Comment: _...its varchar(500)..._ Never choose `varchar` for dates, choose `date` or `datetime`

Comment: would it solve the problem if I changed it?

Comment: _would it solve the problem if I changed it?..._ Oh yes it would!

Comment: @Jaz it is recommended to use mysql dattime type

Comment: datetime does not support "AM or P\M" in the end of it.

Comment: _datetime does not support "AM or P\M"..._ `DATE_FORMAT()` is your friend.. sometimes google does do a very good job!

Comment: @B001ᛦ it does not work. But the worst is that all my values in order_date converted into date :(

Comment: @Jaz wait pls giving a workable solution. It is not straightforward. In future, never consider storing date/datetime as varchar.

Comment: _worst is that all my values in order_date converted into date..._ Have you missed to make a back up before changing the type? OMG

Comment: Yeah I lost all of them. But thankyou for helping me out, though it doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

**Ideal Solution**: You will need to change the datatype of `order_date` from `Varchar(500)` to [`Datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type, using [`Alter Table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) command.

Now, it is noteworthy that the MySQL datetime value is in **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** format. So firstly, you will need to change your datetime string to MySQL datetime format string. **Otherwise, directly changing the datatype will lead to irreparable loss/truncation of data**.

Your datetime value `2018-10-29 01:21:29pm` is basically of **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS AM/PM** (12 hour format). In terms of format specifiers, it would be: `'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s%p'`. Complete list of available format specifiers can be seen in [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

**Firstly**, we use [`Str_To_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert all your data into proper Datetime format.

```
UPDATE orders 
SET order_date = STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s%p');
```

Now, next step is simple. Just modify the datatype to `datetime`:

```
ALTER TABLE orders 
MODIFY COLUMN order_date datetime;
```

Comment: this suggestion is only for converting my varchar to datetime without losing my data right? but this doesnt my problem. The problem is scanning my data in db even it has time included on it.

Comment: @Jaz did you do the mentioned steps and changed the datatype to datetime ?

Comment: @Jaz how does the input datetime string from your PHP code looks like ?

Comment: echoing the $fromdate and $todate resulted to :2018-10-29
2018-10-30

Comment: and the query I used : SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date >='$fromdate' AND order_date <='$todate'

Comment: @Jaz for upper bound check, use `< 2018-10-30` or use `2018-10-29 23:59:59`